# If zero found in Matrix. make entire row & column zero

Tags: java, array, matrix

**Problem is - If in an MxN matrix, a zero is encountered, the entire row and entire column should be set to zero.**

Example -

```
8   4   2
2   3   7
1   0   1
9   8   4
```

Should become:

```
8   0   2
2   0   7
0   0   0
9   0   4
```

I encountered this problem today and came up with a solution.
I'm hoping for some feedback regarding the time/space complexity and how efficient my solution is :

Code -

```
 public static void zeroMatrix(int[][] arr1)
{
    ArrayList<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<>();

    int row = arr1.length; 
    int column = arr1[0].length;
    for(int i=0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < column; j++)
        {
            if(arr1[i][j]==0)
            { 
                coord.add((10*i) + j);
            }       
        }
    }

    for(int n : coord)
    {
         int j=n%10;
         int i=n/10; int k=0;
        int l=0;
        while(k<row)
        {
            arr1[k][j]=0;
            k++;
        }
        while(l<column)
        {
            arr1[i][l]=0;
            l++;
        }
    }
}
```

**What I'm doing is:**

1. Saving the coordinates of found zeroes in an ArrayList as a two
   digit integer.
2. Taking out ones and tens places from the stored
   list (which are the coordinates) and running a loop over the found
   zeroes only.
3. Then making the corresponding rows and columns 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Implementation**

You did it right that you first find the zero entries and only after that set the rows/columns to zero. However, you can come up with more cohesive and flexible code:

```
public static void zeroMatrix(final int[][] matrix) {
    findZeroEntries(matrix).forEach((p) -> { 
        setToZero(matrix, p.x, p.y); 
    });
}

private static List<Point> findZeroEntries(final int[][] matrix) {
    final int height = matrix.length; 
    final int width  = matrix[0].length;
    final List<Point> zeroEntryList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
            if (matrix[y][x] == 0) {
                zeroEntryList.add(new Point(x, y));
            }
        }
    }

    return zeroEntryList;
}

private static void setToZero(final int[][] matrix, 
                              final int x, 
                              final int y) {
    setRowToZero(matrix, y);
    setColumnToZero(matrix, x);
}

private static void setRowToZero(final int[][] matrix, final int y) {
    final int width = matrix[0].length;

    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        matrix[y][x] = 0;
    }
}

private static void setColumnToZero(final int[][] matrix, final int x) {
    final int height = matrix.length;

    for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
        matrix[y][x] = 0;
    }
}
```

**Coding conventions**

*Braces*

What comes to braces, the recommended way to write them is to put the opening brace (`{`) on the same row with the statement that belongs to it. Instead of

```
for (...) 
{
    ...
}
```

you should write

```
for (...) {
    ...
}
```

*Spaces*

For the sake of readability, you should have a single space character after each `for` and `if`, and a single space character **before** and **after** any binary operator. So instead of

```
for(int i=0; ...) {
    if(i==1) {

    }
}
```

you should have

```
for (int i = 0; ...) {
    if (i == 1) {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Program to interface*

Not that it makes much difference in your method, but usually the rule goes that people should program to an interface, and not to an implementation. So instead of

```
ArrayList<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<>();
```

you should write

```
List<Integer> coord = new ArrayList<>();
```

*Naming*

`arr1` is not the best possible name. Why not use, say, `matrix`?

Also

```
int row = arr1.length; 
int column = arr1[0].length;
```

above I would have used the plural form:

```
int rows = arr1.length; 
int columns = arr1[0].length;
```

*Zero entry coordinates*

As @200_success mentioned, packing the coordinates the way you do is not a good idea.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "*What comes to braces, the recommended way to write them*" sounds a little unfounded, [here is one source](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.1-braces) to back that up. I think it is up to personal taste and prefer almann style.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive suggestions! Will take them into account. However, I do agree with @I'll add comments tomorrow , for braces I prefer the almann style as it appears neater and aligned :)

Comment: OK, I admit it, the issue is a matter of style. :-)

Comment: One more question - we have to create a class 'Point' using your implementation, right?

Comment: @borb183 No, it's here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html

Comment: I suppose the line`zeroEntryList.add(new Point(x, y));`
should be : 
`zeroEntryList.add(new Point(y, x));`
  The x,y coordinates are getting swapped

Comment: @borb183 I put x-coordinates into `Point.x` and y-coordinates into `Point.y`.

Comment: But the loop works taking y as row coordinate and x as column coordinate . so it becomes (y,x). Then if you store it as Point(x,y) it's taking the for-loop y and x, as x and y. I ran the code

Comment: @borb183 You are right! I will fix this ASAP.

Comment: @borb183 Done! Thank you for letting me see the issue. All I did is to swap the parameters `x` and `y` in the declaration of `setToZero`.

Comment: @coderodde Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Storing an (i, j) pair as a two-digit number is a nasty hack.  The code will break horribly if there are ten or more rows or columns.  If you must do such a hack, you could pack two `int`s into a `long`:

```
ArrayList<Long> coord = new ArrayList<>();
…
coord.add(i << 32 | j);
```

Writing an [`IntPair`](//stackoverflow.com/q/10234487/1157100) class would be less hackish, though.

Comment: You're correct. This was a brute force solution and I couldn't understand any better way to store coordinate without an additional class.
Thanks for the suggestion !